# Como puedo obtener una referencia a un CheckBox dentro de un GridView (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto ASP.NET (Framework) y estoy frente al problema de que cuando intento obtener la información de un **CheckBox** dentro de una **GridView** (si esta marcado o no), me devuelve un objeto tipo **null**. Todo esto lo estoy intentando hacer **dentro del evento gvUsuarios_RowUpdating2**.

Dentro del archivo .ASPX utilizo dos CheckBox, **uno que solo sirve para ver que esta marcado** (en este caso es un CheckBox deshabilitado) antes de editarlo y **otro para modificarlo**.

Me han dicho que solo utilice un CheckBox debido a que el programa por alguna razón esta tomando el ID del CheckBox que solo se usa para ver la información (que no tengo ni idea como pasa eso) pero aun así termino recibiendo un objeto null.

Si alguien sabe como resolver este problema lo apreciaría muchísimo.

.ASPX:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Administrador">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="read" Enabled="false" Checked='<%# Bind("premium") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox" Checked='<%# Bind("premium") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C#

```
protected void gvUsuarios_RowUpdating2(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow filaSeleccionada = gvUsuarios.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    string usuario = gvUsuarios.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();

    CheckBox admin = (filaSeleccionada.FindControl("checkbox") as CheckBox);

    for (int i = 0; i < Data.usuarios.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Data.usuarios[i].getNombreUsuario() == usuario)
        {
            if (usuario != "admin")
            {
                Data.usuarios[i].setPremium(admin.Checked);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    gvUsuarios.EditIndex = -1;
    gvUsuarios.DataSource = Data.usuarios;
    gvUsuarios.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Tu tienes una clase digamos que `Usuarios` y tienes una propiedad que es booleana `premiun`, cuando editas la grilla la clase debería actualizarse automáticamente sin tu hacer nada, que es justamente lo que hace el `Bind` en el aspx que tu tienes

Answer (score 0):

Lo recomendado que no webcontrol Gridview si necesitas recuperar lo que estas "editando", no lo busques en el webcontrol enlazado, sino en el propio evento que tiene los valores que se estan "cambiando" los valores actualizado (tambien tiene los anteriores, pero depende de como lo enlazas)

En el evento [RowUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating?view=netframework-4.8.1) del Gridview, tienes la posibilidad "generalmente" de obtener los valores nuevos [NewValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues?view=netframework-4.8.1) y los anteriores [OldValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues?view=netframework-4.8.1)

Es "generalmente" porque depende como "bindeas" el gridview. Textual de la ayuda del evento

> Las Keyscolecciones , OldValues y NewValues solo se rellenan automáticamente cuando el GridView control está enlazado a los datos mediante la DataSourceID propiedad .

Pero si lo haces como indicas en tu codigo

```
gvUsuarios.DataSource = Data.usuarios;
```

Si lo podrás obtener y realizar las acciones que necesites a los valores "nuevos" [NewValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues?view=netframework-4.8.1) porque como no esta enlazado mediante DataSourceID no se obtiene los anteriores valores (pero no creo que lo necesites ya que seguramente lo requieres para poder actualizar en la fuente de datos)

Esto  de obtener los "nuevos" [NewValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues?view=netframework-4.8.1) valores es util para no ir "hasta el webcontrol enlazadado" dentro del griview, sino mas bien a los datos (tambien se puede obtener el valor del dato que se encuentra enalazado como lo indican en los comentarios)

Ejemplo
Genera un ejemplo rapido para que se pueda "visualizar" de obtener los "valores nuevos",
En este respositorio https://github.com/fernandezja/aspnet-webforms-experiments
Puedes buscar el webform con el nombre

- /Gridview/Gridview_Checkboxes.aspx

Puedes ver en el evento GridView1_RowUpdating, puedes verlo aquí
https://github.com/fernandezja/aspnet-webforms-experiments/blob/96169ac6319c1ecda0623e715b9a8983c25c8426/src/WebApplication1/Gridview/Gridview_Checkboxes.aspx.cs#L48

Donde el codigo de ejemplo

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
     var newName = e.NewValues["Name"];
     var newIsEnabled = e.NewValues["IsEnabled"];

 }
```

Para verificar con la imagen en modo "debug"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedas con esto obtener el valor que se esta actualizando

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.